# How to create a class and connect it with an existing table in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to Django, and I have a SQL Server database. I don't want to create a class and make a migration because I already have a table with its data. Migration will create a new table for the class. I want to create a class and connect it with the existing table in models.py. How can I do that?

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[login](
    [lo_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lo_username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lo_password] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [lo_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lo_email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the connection in the sittings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'DjangoTest',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'p@$$W0rd',
        'HOST': 'HostName\\SQLSRV2019',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: You can run `inspectdb` to construct a model based on the tables of the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

That will generate python model classes of the existing table isn't in the db.. write the output to models.py and check it out

```
python manage.pymakemigrations
```

Now we need to migrate, that will create the required tables in the database in accordance to the models in model.py. But we already have those tables.. that's where fake migration comes in..

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Before starting read this.. and understand what you are doing.. this will enable you to make django orm queries without using SQL.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#migrate